# Interpretation of instructions without effect

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, instructions

How can we interpret the following program and its success?(Its obvious that there must not be any error message). I mean how does compiler interpret lines 2 and 3 inside main?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a,b;
a; //(2)
b; //(3)
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As statement with no effect.

Comment: The compiler doesn't "interpret" anything. It just implements the rules of the language. The language says that the expression is evaluated and the result discarded.

Comment: @KerrekSB What the expression is evaluated to then(I mean the result) ?

Comment: @GauravJain Since they are uninitialized, I think the result is undefined.

Comment: @Jashaszun: More precisely, the value is *indeterminate*. But since it's immediately discarded, there is no way to attempt to determine the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
a;
```

is just an expression statement. As always in C, the full expression in expression statement is evaluated and its result is immediately discarded.

For example, this

```
a = 2 + 3;
```

is an expression statement containing full expression `a = 2 + 3`. That expression evaluates to `5` and also has a side-effect of writing `5` into `a`. The result is evaluated and discarded.

Expression statement

```
a;
```

is treated in the same way, except that is has no side-effects. <strike>Since you forgot to initialize your variables, evaluation of the above expression can formally lead to undefined behavior.</strike>

Obviously, practical compilers will simply skip such expression statements entirely, since they have no observable behavior.

Comment: This is not UB, since there is no lvalue conversion happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is just like you try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    1;
    2;
    return 0;
}
```

As we can see we have here two expressions followed by semicolon (1; and 2;). It is a well formed statement according to the rules of the language.

There is nothing wrong with it, it is just useless.

But if you try to use though statements (a or b) the behavior will be undefined.
Of course that, the compiler will interpret it as a statement with no effect

L.E:

If you run this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int a;
int b;

printf("A = %d\n",a);
printf("B = %d\n",b);

    if (a < b){
        printf("TRUE");
    }else{
        printf("FALSE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You wil get:

> A = 0
>       B = 0
>       FALSE

Because **a** and **b** are set to **0**;

Comment: You might get false or true, or maybe an infinite loop, or anything else at all. It's undefined behavior to use an uninitialized variable, and the compiler can choose to do whatever is most convenient for it.

Comment: I did explained that, its wrong only if you try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Sentences in C wich are not control structures (if, switch, for, while, do while) or control statements (break, continue, goto, return) are expressions.

Every expression has a resulting value.
An expression is evaluated for its side effects (change the value of an object, write a file, read volatile objects, and functions doing some of these things).

The final result of such an expression is always discarded.
For example, the function printf() returns an int value, that in general is not used. However this value is produced, and then discarded.
However the function printf() produces side effects, so it has to be processed.

If a sentence has no side effects, then the compiler is free to discard it at all.

I think that for a compiler will not be so hard to check if a sentence has not any side effects. So, what you can expect in this case is that the compiler will choose to do nothing.

Moreover, this will not affect the observable behaviour of the program, so there is no difference in what is obtained in the resulting execution of the program. However, of course, the program will run faster if any computation is ignored at all by the compiler.

Also, note that in some cases the floating point environment can set flags, which are considered side-effects.

The [Standard C (C11)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says, as part of paragraph 5.1.2.3p.4:

> An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it
>   can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects
>   are produced [...]

**CONCLUSION:** One has to read the documentation of the particular compiler that oneself is using.

Answer (score 0):

That's why you should use some compilation warning flags!
-Wall would trigger a "statement with no effect" warning.

If you want to see what the compilation produces, compile using -S.
Try it with your code, with/without -O (optimization) flag...